# Update Time according to the timezone in javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, date, timestamp

I have `time` returned from the database in a form of `2015-03-13 02:08:18`
It is set to 00:00 timezone, but I need to convert it to user's time in order to show 'how many hours/minutes/seconds' ago it was. Is there a simple function that will do the work? (I know, this is probably already answered, but all the examples I found so far are doing the reverse thing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `Z` on the end to tell JavaScript to parse it as UTC, and replace the space with a `T` so it works in IE (thanks [@Salman A](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87015/salman-a)):

```
var timestampFromDatabase = '2015-03-13 02:08:18';
var dateInUsersTimezone = new Date(timestampFromDatabase.replace(' ', 'T') + 'Z');
```

For example, in California:

```
new Date('2015-03-13T02:08:18Z');
// Thu Mar 12 2015 19:08:18 GMT-0700 (PDT)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the timezone is known (for example `+00:00`) then all you need to do is this:

```javascript
var d1 = new Date("2015-03-13T02:08:18+00:00");
var d2 = new Date();
var diff = d2 - d1;
// diff contains the number of milliseconds between the two dates
```

The difference is independent of user timezone.